# Активация триггера вложенного блока, без активации триггера родительского блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть два блока, второй вложен в первый и имеет position:absolute;. На оба блока повешены эвенты, и при нажатии на второй блок активируются оба эвента. Что нужно сделать в триггере родительского блока, что бы при нажатии на дочерний блок - вызывался только его эвент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".block1").on("click", function() {
  alert(1);
})
$(".block2").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert(2);
})
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
}
.block1 {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: #333;
  position: relative;
}
.block2 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="block1">
    <div class="block2"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```